# How to find an email in a folder?

Tags: gmail

I accidentally hit the folder button on my Gmail account instead of *print* and now the email has vanished.

How can I find it again? Also, is there anything I can set up to bring up a prompt box so that I don't do it again?

Comment: What do you mean by “folder” button? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Also, if you know who sent you the respective email, or at list some keyword from it, you can search for it from the search box. If you know the sender, you can simply type `from:sendersaddress@example.com` in the search box.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you moved the e-mail to a folder/label by clicking the folder icon and selecting a label.

To find it in that folder, just type "label:foldername" followed by some keywords in the e-mail.